# Curl alert after loading big pages

Tags: php, curl

I am using the below command to fetch the content of a URL.

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I want to parse the resultant text. Now what I am doing is to parse the content of `$result` after waiting for a fixed delay to make sure that the whole page is loaded and the full content of page is available with the variable `$result`.

Is there any alternate ways which I can identify whether the whole page is loaded or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're using `curl_multi_exec`, `curl_exec` will not return anything until the entire page is loaded, so there is no need to do what you are trying to do. From the [manual page](http://php.net/curl_exec):

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the
>   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on
>   success, FALSE on failure.

It won't return anything and your script won't continue until the transfer has finished.

**Edit::**

It is a bit confusing what is actually happening, but it looks like you are displaying the HTML contents of a page to the browser and that page is redirecting the user to a new page. I'm guessing that this is either a javascript or meta refresh. The only way to prevent this from happening is by parsing through the HTML and removing those elements.

Try adding `header('Content-type: text/plain');` to the top of your script and you will see what is actually returned by curl.

Comment: But as i said the problem is loaded page contains an header to another page.
I want to wait till the next page loads completely.
Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` ?

Comment: This will work if the redirect is in the header-data but not if it is in the html code itself and delayed.

Comment: @TobiasKun see my edit. I wasn't sure exactly what the OP was talking about.

Comment: @Mike: No problem :) Like you said it was unclear what type of redirect it is and which page IntelligentYahoo wanted to receive.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an delay or something else.

When you get the result back from curl it contains the whole page.

Comment: actually a page will be displayed and immediately the same will be redirected to another page which is the final page in which the content to be parsed is there.
Now on parsing the text, i am getting those contents in the previous page.

Comment: But you won't get the content from the next page because curl will return the content of the first and then stops. You have to query the last page itself.